# Is entropy conserved in an isolated system with two containers of gas separated by a diathermal wall at different initial energies?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, conservation-laws, entropy

Question is pretty much the title. If I take a system of two gases and allow them to exchange heat I can write the total entropy as

$$S_{total}=S_A+S_B=k_b(\ln{\Omega_A+\ln{\Omega_B})}.$$

Will ths quantity be conserved as the two systems exchange heat with each other? Is the answer different if the walls of the container are not allowed to absorb (and hence dissipate) any energy exchanged between the gases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entropy will increase, remember that $dS=dQ/T$, so the side with the lower temperature increases its entropy more than it diminishes on the side with the largest temperature.

The number of accessible micro states will differ after the heat exchange, so at the beginning you have:
$$S_{total}=S_A+S_B=k_b(\ln{\Omega_A+\ln{\Omega_B})}$$

and after the heat exchange:

$$S'_{total}=S'_A+S'_B=k_b(\ln{\Omega'_A+\ln{\Omega'_B})}>S_{total}$$

Comment: Solved, thank you.